# Change npm-debug.log location

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run `npm start` and there is some error, it says:

```
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hsz/Projects/project/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

And this file is located in a directory from which I have called `npm`.

Is it possible to set `npm-debug.log` output file to `./logs/npm-debug.log` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

npm [pull request #6744](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/6744) tries to move `npm-debug.log` from cwd into the cache folder.

---

**Original Answer:**

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this. It is hardcoded:

In [`error-handler.js`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/utils/error-handler.js#L25)

```
if (wroteLogFile) {
  log.error("", [""
            ,"Additional logging details can be found in:"
            ,"    " + path.resolve("npm-debug.log")
            ].join("\n"))
  wroteLogFile = false
}
log.error("not ok", "code", code)
```

And [other](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/utils/error-handler.js#L54) [occurrences](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/utils/error-handler.js#L325) [as well](https://github.com/npm/fstream-npm/blob/master/fstream-npm.js#L109).

I don't think this flexibility would fit into `npm`'s philosophy see [isaacs comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775#issuecomment-962144):

> `npm config set prefix`?
>
> If you want to spell "node_modules" differently, sorry, no can do.
>   That's built into node-core. Changing that is tantamount to building a
>   completely different package manager.

Comment: That comment has nothing to do with the npm-debug.log, changing the node_modules directory location is a whole different story, more accurate discussion: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5252

Comment: Thanks @IanWalter, I've updated my answer, and yes the comment is not directly related.

Answer (score 0):

## [RFC 499](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/499)

I opened up an [RFC 499](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/499) to make this request. Please consider upvoting it for visibility or commenting with your own ideas on how this feature should look. This will track the progress and input under the official `npm/rfcs` project.

- https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/499